# Sed processed file displays differently in vi vs cat

Tags: sed, vi, xterm

I can't tell if `sed` is mucking my file up.  In `vi` or `less` it displays properly, but `cat` and `more` insert other characters.  why are they showing up differently

I am on a redhat linux system with a standard xterm.

the raw tab file before:

```
scaffold1000    693:14709284:741:333    129011535   1
scaffold1000    693:14709284:27:726 129011535   1
scaffold1000    693:14709284:44:1157    129011535   1
scaffold1000    693:14709284:771:459    129011535   1
scaffold1000    693:14709284:610:615    129011535   1
scaffold1000    693:14709284:1152:1159  129011535   1
```

applying `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/scaffold/scaffold\_/' [myfile]
```

I've also tried this without the backslash to the same result.

Using `cat` I see this :

```
scaffold11000   693:14709284:741:333    129011535   1
scaffold11000   693:14709284:27:726 129011535   1
scaffold11000   693:14709284:44:1157    129011535   1
scaffold11000   693:14709284:771:459    129011535   1
scaffold11000   693:14709284:610:615    129011535   1
```

Where did that '1' come from?  :(

editing in `vi` or using `less` I see:

```
scaffold_1000   693:14709284:741:333    129011535       1^M     1^M     1       
scaffold_1000   693:14709284:27:726     129011535       1^M     1^M     1       
scaffold_1000   693:14709284:44:1157    129011535       1^M     1^M     1       
scaffold_1000   693:14709284:771:459    129011535       1^M     1^M     1       
scaffold_1000   693:14709284:610:615    129011535       1^M     1^M     1       
scaffold_1000   693:14709284:1152:1159  129011535       1^M     1^M     1
```

Do the `^M` chars have something to do with this? Its like I can't trust my own eyes here...

Comment: I can't see how that have happend. Can you start with a fresh file and check that you can repeat that behaviour?

Comment: I think @JimParis nailed this - take a look below.  this is definitely reproducible.  its just odd how the formatting conspires to make exactly the same change in all the lines I looked at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each line of the file contains the string

```
^M     1
```

twice.  That is,

```
<carriage-return><tab>1
^M^I1
\r\t1
```

(Those are three different representations of the same control characters)

When this is sent directly to your terminal, as `cat` will do, the
terminal interprets this as an instruction to move back to the beginning of the line, move over 8 characters, and display a `1`.

When you `cat` the original file, this additional `1` shows up on top of an existing `1`, so you didn't notice it.

After you changed the prefix from `scaffold` to `scaffold_`, the additional `1` now shows up over the `_`, so now you noticed it.

When you open the file in `vi` or `emacs`, the editor doesn't interpret the `<carriage-return>` sequence the same way, but instead displays it.

I assume you don't want the `<carriage-return><tab>1` strings in your file.  You can remove them with `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\r\t1//g' myfile
```

---

Regarding your "I can't trust my own eyes" comment -- since control sequences change how things get displayed, yeah, they can be confusing.  One way to view things more clearly is with `cat`'s `-v` and `-T` options:

```
-v, --show-nonprinting   use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
-T, --show-tabs          display TAB characters as ^I
-t                       equivalent to -vT
```

For example:

```
$ cat myfile
scaffold1test
$ cat -t myfile
scaffold_hello^M^I1
```

Answer (score -1):

`^M` is a carriage return.

you can use `dos2unix <file>` to strip the DOS keys out of your file

Comment: `dos2unix` will convert line **endings** from `CRLF` to `LF`.  There are no `CRLF` sequences in this file; just bare CRs (not at the end of lines).

Comment: how did you know that just by looking at the excerpt from his output?

Comment: From what he copied out of `vi` and `less`.  They showed the bare `CR`s directly in the middle of the lines.  Also, it fully explains the behavior he's seeing.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have `dos2unix`, you can do it with `sed` :

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' <THE FILE NAME>
```

It will remove all carriage returns.

Comment: This command isn't equivalent to `dos2unix`.  `dos2unix` strips the `CR` from a `CRLF`; this command will strip `CR` everywhere.  But the asker's file has more than just stray `CR`s, so this will leave it with the extraneous `TAB` and `1` characters too.